# Elastic search status is running but still getting no reply on curl localhost:9200

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search in my laravel project using package elasticquent, I followed this specific tutorial
[Laravel Elastic Search](https://appdividend.com/2022/06/17/laravel-elasticsearch/)

and before that I installed elastic search on my OS(Ubuntu) by following the documentation.
After setting all things I get no reply error after spending some time on error I ran to some solution which says I have to make changes in my elasticsearch.yml file

***Changes I made***

```
cluster.name = <my-cluster-name>

node.name = <my-node-name> //basically my System name
```

I got credentials for above field by the following command

```
curl --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic http://localhost:9200
```

which gives response as follows

```
{
  "name" : "Cp8oag6",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "AT69_T_DTp-1qgIJlatQqA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.4.1",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "f27399d",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_date" : "2016-03-30T09:51:41.449Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.3.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "1.2.3",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "1.2.3"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

so after doing all setup and following the tutorial when I visit my search url I get
`No nodes alive` and If I try
curl -X GET localhost:9200 It gives no reply error.

Comment: what do the Elasticsearch logs show?

Comment: I have same problem in one of my project and after a lot of debugging I found that there is some issue inside the package so that I changed the elascticserch package and now it is working fine. 
My working package link :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/installation.html